# I am not able to save my form data to mysql database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, forms, insert

I am a bit newbie in PHP and having real trouble here, I dont know the reason why it does not save form data, please help me if you find something wrong. i had tried a lot to edit but it does not work at all. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php  
session_start();  

if(!$_SESSION['username'])  
{  

    header("Location: index.php");//redirect to login page to secure the welcome page without login access.  
}

?> 

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Registeration Form</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/view.css" media="all">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/view.js"></script>
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="js/forms.js"></script>

</head>
    <body id="main_body" >

        <img id="top" src="images/top.png" alt="">
        <div id="form_container">
            <h1>Registeration Form</h1>
            <div id="wrap">
            <!-- Here's all it takes to make this navigation bar. -->
               <ul id="nav">
                  <li><a href="manage.php">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="register.php">Register</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">View</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
                  <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
               </ul>
            <!-- That's it! -->
            </div>

            <form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="POST"  class="appnitro">
            <div class="form_description">
                <h2>Registeration Form</h2>
                <p>Please fill the form</p>
            </div>                      

                    <label class="description">Name </label>
                    <input name="name" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/>


                    <label class="description">Email </label>
                    <input name="email" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 


                    <label class="description" >Department </label>                 
                    <input name="department" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 


                    <label class="description">Respective Professor</label>
                    <input name="professor" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 


                    <label class="description">Position</label>
                    <select class="element select medium" name="position"> 
                        <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
                        <option value="Student-Bachelors" >Student-Bachelors</option>
                        <option value="Student-Masters" >Student-Masters</option>
                        <option value="Student-PhD" >Student-PhD</option>
                        <option value="Internee" >Internee</option>
                        <option value="Employee" >Employee</option>
                    </select>


                    <label class="description">Duration</label>
                    <span>
                    <input name= "duration_start" class="element text" maxlength="255" size="14" value=""/>
                    <label>Start</label>
                    </span>
                    <span>
                    <input name= "duration_end" class="element text" maxlength="255" size="14" value=""/>
                    <label>End</label>
                    </span> 

                    <label class="description">Room & Building</label>
                    <span>
                    <input  name= "room" class="element text" maxlength="255" size="14" value=""/>
                    <label>Room</label>
                    </span>
                    <span>
                    <input name= "building" class="element text" maxlength="255" size="14" value=""/>
                    <label>Building</label>
                    </span> 

                    <label class="description" >Address </label>
                    <input name="address" class="element text large" value="" type="text">


                    <label class="description" >Phone Number </label>   
                    <input name="phone_number" class="element text" maxlength="255" value="" type="text">

                    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Create my account" title="" border="0">

            </form> 

            <div id="footer"> Login as:
                <?php  
                    echo $_SESSION['username'];
                ?>, 

            </div>
        </div>
            <img id="bottom" src="images/bottom.png" alt="">
    </body>
</html>

<?php  

require_once("db_connect.php");//make connection here  
if(isset($_POST['submit']))  
{  
    $name=$_POST['name'];//here getting result from the post array after submitting the form.    
    $email=$_POST['email'];//same
    $department=$_POST['department'];//same 
    $professor=$_POST['professor'];//same
    $position=$_POST['position'];//same
    $duration_start=$_POST['duration_start'];//same
    $duration_end=$_POST['duration_end'];//same
    $room=$_POST['room'];//same
    $building=$_POST['building'];//same
    $address=$_POST['address'];//same
    $phone_number=$_POST['phone_number'];//same

    if($name=='')  
    {  
        //javascript use for input checking  
        echo"<script>alert('Please enter the name')</script>";  
    exit();//this use if first is not work then other will not show  
    }  

    if($email=='')  
    {  
        echo"<script>alert('Please enter the email')</script>";  
    exit();  
    }  

    if($department=='')  
    {  
        echo"<script>alert('Please enter the department')</script>";  
    exit();  
    }  

    if($professor=='')  
    {   
        echo"<script>alert('Please enter the professor')</script>";  
    exit();
    }  

    if($position=='')  
    {  
        echo"<script>alert('Please enter the position')</script>";  
    exit();  
    }  

    if($duration_start=='')  
    {  
        echo"<script>alert('Please enter the duration end')</script>";  
    exit();  
    }  
    if($duration_end=='')  
    {   
        echo"<script>alert('Please enter the duration start')</script>";  
    exit();
    }  

    if($room=='')  
    {  
        echo"<script>alert('Please enter the room')</script>";  
    exit();  
    }  

    if($building=='')  
    {  
        echo"<script>alert('Please enter the building')</script>";  
    exit();  
    }  
    if($address=='')  
    {  
        echo"<script>alert('Please enter the address')</script>";  
    exit();  
    }  

    if($phone_number=='')  
    {  
        echo"<script>alert('Please enter the phone number')</script>";  
    exit();  
    }  

    //here query check weather if user already registered so can't register again.  
    $check_email_query="select * from new_members WHERE email='$email'";  
    $run_query=mysqli_query($mysqli,$check_email_query);  

    if(mysqli_num_rows($run_query)>0)  
    {  
        echo "<script>alert('Email $email is already exist in our database, Please try another one!')</script>";  
        exit();  
    } 

    //insert the user into the database.  
    $insert_user="insert into new_members(name,email,professor,department,position,duration_start,duration_end,room,building,address,phone_number) VALUES ('$name','$email','$professor','$department','$position','$duration_start','$duration_end','$room','$building','$address','$phone_number')";  
    if(mysqli_query($mysqli,$insert_user))  
    {  
         header("Location:manage.php");
         exit();
        //echo "<script>window.open('manage.php','_self')</script>";  
     }
   }
?>
```

Comment: This form comes when a user sign in, this is just to save data in database, but it does not, just come up with the same form after submission.

Comment: Be on the lookout for [injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: Used JQuery validation for form

Comment: if(!$_SESSION['username'])  
{  

    header("Location: index.php");//redirect to login page to secure the welcome page without login access.  
}

remove this line..

Comment: What is the error that you get

Comment: AAli, this question is not answerable (or not easily) as you have not told us what error you're getting or how far you got.  I can say that your `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` block should really go above your form.  What I suggest you do is a) do a hard coded query to your database to both insert and update and b) make sure the data is of the correct format and that you're getting it.

Comment: temporarily change your code `mysqli_query($mysqli,$insert_user)` to `mysqli_query($mysqli,$insert_user) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli))` and tell us what is the exact error your getting

Comment: What error you are getting? and make sure your database connection is correct?

Comment: Yes My database connection is correct, the problem is the when I enter the form it does not insert data into the database table, after clicking the submit button, the registeration page comes without going to the header location and without inserting the data in the table.